# Python passing a list from a file to requests.get()

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape a corpus of news article for analysis. I have a text file with a list of URL's and I'm trying to pass these to requests so that the page can be scraped with BeautifulSoup. I can pull the urls from the text file. However, I'm not properly passing that outputto  requests.get(). When I give requests.get() an explicit url, the script works fine. **How do I properly pass to requests.get() a list of links from a text file?** Here is what I have working.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("https://examplewebsite.org/page1")
coverpage = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(coverpage, 'html5lib')
file = open("output.txt", "w")
file.write("ITEM:")
paragraphs = soup.find_all("p")[11:-10]
for paragraph in paragraphs:
    file.write(paragraph.get_text())
    file.write("\n")
    file.write("\n")
file.close()
```

However, when I try to read from a text file that is a list of links, there seems to be a problem with how I'm passing the links to requests.get(). With one URL per line, the text file list of links looks like

> https://examplewebsite.org/page1
>   https://examplewebsite.org/page2
>   https://examplewebsite.org/page3
>   https://examplewebsite.org/page4

Here is how I'm trying to work through the list of links.

```
f = open('article-list.txt', 'r')
urls = list(f)
for url in urls:
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    r = requests.get(url)
    coverpage = r.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(coverpage, 'html5lib')
    file = open("output.txt", "w")
    file.write("ITEM:")
    paragraphs = soup.find_all("p")[11:-10]
    for paragraph in paragraphs:
        file.write(paragraph.get_text())
        file.write("\n")
        file.write("\n")
        print(paragraph.get_text())
file.close()
```

What I get is an error saying

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'`

This suggests to me I'm not properly passing the request. If I simply swap an explicitly defined url like "https://somewebsite.org/page1" then the script works and writes paragraphs to the file. Yet when I put a `print(urls)` statement at the top and give requests.get() an explicit link so it does not break, I get a list of urls. However, that list is formatted as:

['http://examplewebsite.org/page1\n', 'http://examplewebsite.org/page2\n', 'http://examplewebsite.org/page3\n']

I think that **\n** is the problem. I tried running the links all together and that didn't work. Also for readability, I'd much prefer to have each link on a separate line. **Any suggestions for how to address this would be deeply appreciated.** Thanks.

Comment: did you try removing the \n using the str method str. rstrip('\n') ?

Comment: So I tried `page_url = url_list.rstrip("\n")` which resulted in "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rstrip'". I also tried `r = requests.get(page_url.rstrip("\n"))` which produced the same error. Reading about rstrip() it seems like its the right thing, but I'm not yet sure where to place it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Dear @Sureshmani, this worked! My issue is that I didn't know how to use it properly. However, I fiddled around and stumbled my way to a solution which I will post below. Thanks for the good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing "\n" with the use of .rstrip() solved the issue. The code below is working and properly writes a group of news items to a single text file.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = open('article-list.txt', 'r')
urls_n = list(f)
urls = [url.rstrip("\n") for url in urls_n]

for url in urls:
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    r = requests.get(url)
    coverpage = r.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(coverpage, 'html5lib')
    file = open("output.txt", "a")
    file.write("ITEM:")
    paragraphs = soup.find_all("p")[11:-10]
    for paragraph in paragraphs:
        file.write(paragraph.get_text())
        file.write("\n")
        file.write("\n")
        print(paragraph.get_text())
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the list just as they are in the file, this line

```
urls = list(f)
```

should look like this

```
urls = f.readlines()
```

It will return an array of every line in the txt file without any "\n"

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I was not aware of readlines(). Unfortunately, f.readlines() still leaves "\n" present just the same as with list(f). I can't see any difference in the output. It seems that split may be a way to approach this, but I am not completely sure. I will keep looking, thanks.